# Type Casting Issue in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I've got a problem with type casting from base class to derived (I'm casting because I'm sure that object is that exact type). 
here's my code (simplified):

```
class MyCollection 
{
public:
 Element* Get(int i) {
  return elements[i]; 
 }
 void Add(Element* element) {
   //finding i
   elements[i] = element;
 }
private:
 Element* elements[100]; 
}

class Element {
 public:
  int ID; 
}

class SpecialElement : public Element 
{
public:
 SpecialElement(char* name) { 
   this-> Name = name; 
 }
 char* GetName() { return Name; }
private:
 char* Name; 
}
```

Now when I'm add to MyCollection object of SpecialElement when I put breakpoint at the moment of adding and cast my argument of Add method in Immediate Window and call GetName method it return me Name of object, but when I do something like this:

```
void main() {
 MyCollection coll = new MyCollection();
 coll.Add(new SpecialElement("MyName"));
 SpecialElement* foundElement = (SpecialElement*)coll->Get(0); 
 foundElement->GetName(); //Error
}
```

I'm wondering why is that? Isn't founded object of type SpecialElement?

Comment: Don't use `void main()`: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: Way overuse of dynamic allocation. And bad use of strings. And abuse of points.

Comment: The collection smells like **slicing** all over...

Comment: Clean up the example code so it compiles (e.g. not mixing pointers and objects, etc.).  Right now it's impossible to tell what is a "real" error amidst all the "fake" typo-type errors.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Reducing your code to the simplest thing that produces the problem is really good idea -- you often end up finding the error on your own that way -- but you should make sure it actually compiles before posting it. This code contains tons of errors, which complicates the task of anyone reviewing it.

Comment: For one `this->Name = name;` in the constructor is very bad code.  You should be doing a deep copy of the string, and given more information about what the error is I suspect this is the root cause of your problem at runtime

Comment: @SachinKainth and future readers: [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Answer (score 6):

```
 Element* Get(int i) {
  return elements[i]; 
 }
 void Add(Element* element) {
   //finding i
   elements[i] = element;
 }
```

How does this even compile? You're assigning an `Element*` to an `Element`, and vice versa, but they are entirely different things. Your whole logic is nonsensical.

You're over-using dynamic allocation, assuming reference semantics, and bad `char*` strings. Get a C++ book.

Also, this class already exists- it's `std::array<Element*, 100>`. Or `std::vector<Element*>`, if you want dynamic size.

Answer (score 6):

You're casting it to base `Element` and thereby slicing your `SpecialElement` object.  The cast back to the original type, from your base `Element` has lost the data `Name` as that is not part of the base.

AFAIK, you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: He can do it, but this storage array needs to contain *pointers* (i.g. `Element* elements[100]` rather than `Element elements[100]`) to avoid slicing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Element* elements[100];` and update your code appropriately, otherwise using object assignment instead of pointer assignment kills polymorphism.